# Using onclick in children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I'm recently using `react-spring` and it works really well but I'm having some issues when I have to apply an `onClick` on childs.

**Here is my main structure:**

```
<anim.button  className="c"
   style={{ opacity: opacity.interpolate(o => 1 - o), transform }}>
   <Bar />
</anim.button>
<anim.button  className="c"
   style={{ opacity, transform: transform.interpolate(t => `${t} 
   rotateX(180deg)`) }}>
   <Bar />
</anim.button>
```

An `onClick` on the `anim.button` would work perfectly fine of course, but that's not what I'm trying.

Here is my `<Bar />` component:

```
  const Bar = () => (
    <div className="bar">
      <Checkbox
        onClick={() => {
          set(state => !state)
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

I also tried using the `<anim.div>` instead of an `<anim.button>` but this gives me the same results.

Now the problem here is that it seems like **`react-spring`** puts a layer onto my **`<Bar />`** component. Is there a way to use the `onClick` in my component instead of the one that is used onto **`anim.button`**?

Comment: set(state => !state) .. where did you get "set" ?

Comment: `set` comes from a React `useState` and holds the animation's current state

Comment: but you don't have it defined anywhere.. or it's just missing in the snippet ?

Comment: Yes it is missing in the snippet, I didn't put the basic `react-spring` setup in there.

Comment: You'll have to pass some onClick function down to Bar so it can use it instead

Comment: That won't work either, even a `console.log()` in an `onClick` will not work. `anim.button` blocks that apparently

Answer (score 1):

Given that Checkbox is also a component and it might not have onClick handled try putting **onClick** on the wrapping div or inspect the Checkbox component.

Comment: Even with a default html button and an onclick it results in nothing

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used react-spring ever but structuring your `Bar` component like this may do the trick.

```
const Bar = (props) => (
<div onClick={() => {set(state => !state)}}>
 <anim.button  {...props}>
   <div className="bar">
     <Checkbox />
   </div>
 </anim.button>
</div>)
```

then rendering it like this:

```
<Bar className={'c'} style={{ opacity: opacity.interpolate(o => 1 - o), transform}}/>
<Bar className="c" style={{ opacity, transform: transform.interpolate(t => `${t}
    rotateX(180deg)`) }}/>
```

Comment: But this will result in the same problem. The while bar is clickable when it shouldn't. Only the checkbox should

Answer (score 0):

You could rather wrap the Bar in a div: `<animated.div>` you are wrapping a button around a checkbox which is not great. `onClick` will trigger as expected.

```
<animated.div className="c"
   style={{ opacity, transform: transform.interpolate(t => `${t} 
   rotateX(180deg)`) }}>
   <Bar />
</animated.div>
```

Comment: This is what I initially did but this don't work either. only the `onClick` on `<animated.div>` is used. The div becomes clickable but not the children

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been found and didn't actually has anything to do with `react-spring`.
The position absolute styling was causing this.